# ZF3 upgrade does not show exceptions anymore in views

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

using ZF2 I was able to show $this->display_exceptions in my views but after upgrading to ZF3 this does not work anymore.

Is this changed as well in ZF3 or am I missing something ?

Comment: well i didnt use zf2 but it seems a little different atm. you can check error view at; 
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml

Comment: Thanks that works out! Going to look @ the differences :)